# How to insert a JPEG picture using LaTeX

Tags: errors, jpeg

I try to insert a picture using the code below

```
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{image/Test}
\caption{Example TA}
\label{fig:Reinforcement}
\end{figure}
```

However, the error says `Missing $ inserted`; may someone help me?

Comment: Don't quite see how you get that error message form the given code snippet.  But, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't know what the `pgf` is for. Usually `\usepackage{graphicx}` is used for JPEGs and pictures in general.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 10):

To end this I include here a complete MWE that compiles without errors (notice, that the used figure is part of package [`MWE`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) you should have installed but must not be loaded). It contains everything needed to print a figure in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%                 use [hb] only if necceccary!
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{test figure}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```