# How to add a picture in TeX (a jpeg)?

Tags: pspicture, bakoma

I saved the jpeg file in the same place where all my TeX files are placed at; which commands should I be using to make the pic appear?

I am using Bakoma TeX 11.85, but I believe it's the same in every software of TeX, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \includegraphics?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301494/how-to-use-includegraphics)

Comment: Or, other related questions: [How to insert a JPEG picture using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82795/), [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by latex or pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072/), [How to use \graphicspath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/), [How to insert images with graphicx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176877/how-to-insert-images-with-graphicx), etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the package `graphicx`: https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx.

It can be employed for a wide range of image types (jpg, png, eps...) and moreover has a lot of useful options to deal with images, such as

- `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{IMAGE.jpg}` it halves the size of the image. You can choose any percentage, even greater than 1.
- `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{IMAGE.jpg}` it rescales the image by setting its width as the 50% of the text width and automatically adjust the height to maintain the proportion. You can choose any percentage: for example, `\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{IMAGE.jpg}` set the width as 1/10 of the textwidth.
- `\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{IMAGE.jpg}` it rescales the image by setting its height as the 50% of the text width and automatically adjust the width to maintain the proportion. You can choose any percentage, also greater than 1.

Comment: How do I shrink the picture? I used the commands just after documentclass \usepackage{graphicx} and in the body of the text I used the command \includegraphicx{(b).jpg} but I believe I get a picture which is too big for the screen so I don't see the picture. What do you suggest me to do here? thanks!

Comment: You can use some options for the `\includegraphics` command, such as `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{(b).jpg}`, which halves the image; you can choose the percentage of the scaling as you desire. Nonetheless, the option that I prefer is to use `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{(b).jpg}` which rescales the image's dimension as a percentage of the width of the text (in this case, it sets as 50% of the text width). You may play a little bit with this commands and see what better suits you.

Comment: @Eddymage --- it would be much better if you put the info in this comment in the answer ;-)

Comment: @Rmano you're right, done it!